# how to call a function continously

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to run this code continuously, so that the function I called is always checking whether entered is true or false

index.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
var entered = require('./main.js').onProximityBoolean; /// i want this to continuously be checking itself
   if (entered == true) {
     socket.emit('enterProximity');
   }
}
```

main.js

```
var enter = false;
function onProximityBoolean(enter) {
  if (enter === true) {
    console.log(enter);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function isWithinBounds() {
  //inside here is sensor code that says if the object comes close 
  //then enter will be true else enter will be false
  //this part accurately redefines the onProximityBoolean
}
module.exports = {
  onProximityBoolean: onProximityBoolean(enter)
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"continuously"_? Have you looked into `setInterval`?

Comment: I mean, it that line of code is always updating itself, checking if entered is true or false

Comment: I think you might be thinking of observables... maybe.

Comment: You want to look into using events.

Comment: I'd also note that `if (enter === true) { return true } else { return false }` can (probably should) always be reduced to just `return enter;`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to implement an *observer* with a setter / getter:

```
"main.js";
var state=false;
var handlers=[];
module.exports={
  get proximityBoolean(){
     return state;
  },
  set proximityBoolean(value){
     if(value!==state){
       state=value;
       handlers.forEach(func=>func(value));
  },
  observe(func){
    handlers.push(func);
  }
}
```

So you can do:

```
var main = require('./main.js');
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 main.observe(function(entered){
  if (entered == true) {
    socket.emit('enterProximity');
   }
  });
}

//trigger it somewhen
main.proximityBoolean=true;
```

---

Alternatively use setInterval to check regularily:

```
var main=require('./main.js');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
 setInterval(function() {
  var entered = main.onProximityBoolean;
  if (entered == true) {
     socket.emit('enterProximity');
   } 
},1000);
});
```

Comment: Your semantics are different than what I'm used to, but +1 for suggesting events.

Comment: @BrettBeatty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Oh, I just meant I'm more used to `addEventListener` than `observe`.

Comment: @BrettBeatty well *observe* is self implemented.

Comment: i used your second option( just changing the code in index.js using the setinterval method, and it says main is not defined

Comment: wait just kidding, is there a way you can call the trigger in a different file? because how i have the sensor code, the only place to put the trigger is in a different file.

Comment: @juniperWhite 1) you may forgot the var main=require(..);? 2) yes shure should work through different files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method. You can use a while(true) loop but that slow the code a lot, so what I suggest you to do is:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    setInterval(function(socket) {
       var entered = require('./main.js').onProximityBoolean;
          if (entered == true) {
             socket.emit('enterProximity');
             } 
      },1000);}); //after 1 second the function will be called [1000ms]
```

Comment: wont work. You need to pass *socket* through the interval

Comment: ya this didnt work, entered is still false even while enter in main.js is true

Comment: @LisnaVargheese Try this now.. I've called a `function(socket){}` and then i setted the interval passing `socket`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use cron jobs . Here [the npm repo and example of use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)